# WPF: Datagrid validation not on a row level but on a collection level

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a datagrid which implements some validation rules. If these latters return that the row is not valid, the row is marked as erroneous (red icon in the row header). Basic stuff.

Now, I would like to implement a validation rule but on the whole collection. For instance, I have a column which displays each source collection item's name and I want this name to be unique throughout the whole collection. When three rows show a shared named, I'd like them all to display the red error icon in the row header.

I thought about raising an event in my model's class whenever this name property is modified, then listen to this event from the view model but it feels wrong coding that. And I don't know whether I can achieve the result (mark rows as erroneous) or not.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I ended up doing, please let me know if this is dirty, bad practice etc.

```
public class MyModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region Fields

    readonly ObservableCollection<MyModel> _parentCollection;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Validation
    string _error;
    public string Error => _error;
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> foundErrors = new List<string>();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnName) ||
                (columnName == nameof(Name) &&
                 _parentCollection.Count(ed => ed.Name == Name) > 1))
            {
                foundErrors.Add("Name already used"));
            }
            _error = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, foundErrors);
            return _error;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public EvaluationDay(ObservableCollection<MyModel> parentCollection)
        : base()
    {
        _parentCollection = parentCollection;
    }

    #endregion

    }
}
```

And then, in my ViewModel, whenever I am adding a MyModel object to the observable collection binded to the view, I make sure to send this OC reference to the object as parameter for the constructor:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    #endregion

    ...

    int elementsToAddCount = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsToAddCount; i++)
    {
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel(MyModels));
    }

    ...
```

This being said, you can also simply add a parameter to the validation rule...